# Repeat or restart an observable (interval) after its completed

Tags: rxjs, observable, repeat, intervals, expand

Here is what I am trying to do - step #3 is what I am struggling with.

1. Set custom interval
2. trigger an http call (subscribe to it)
3. **Once interval is finished, I want to repeat the above steps indefinitely (until a condition is met)**

Steps #1 & #2 are working

```js
setRenewalInterval() {
  ...

  return this.timerSub = interval(CUSTOM_INTERVAL * 1000)
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      map(x => {
        if (this.isLoggedIn && !tokenHelper.isTokenExpired()) {
          console.log("<Requesting Token Renew>")
          this.getNewToken().subscribe(
            x => {
              console.log("<Token renewed successfully>");
            },
            err => {
              console.log("<Token failed to renew>");
              this.setLogOut();
            },
            () => console.log('<renewal observable completed>')
          );
        }
        else {
          console.log("<Not Logged in or Token expired; logging out>");
          this.setLogOut();
        }
      })   
    )
    .subscribe();
 }
```

#3 repeat the above steps after the subscription is completed. Either call `setRenewalInterval()` or preferably do it inside the `setRenewalInterval()`.

I have looked into rxjs `repeat()` and `expand()` but I can't get them to work with the above code. Any help is greatly appreciated, especially a testable/runnable code e.g. jsfiddle.

Comment: repeat() suppose should work if you put it at the end of the pipe()

Comment: Have a look at `repeatWhen()`

Answer (score 0):

You're really close, `interval(...)` is already creating an emission indefinitely however `take(1)` is causing the entire observable to complete after the first emission.

If you remove the `take(1)` your code inside the `map` will be called at your interval forever.

`map` is a useful function when you want to take values emit in an observable and convert it to a new value synchronously, similar to how `Array.map()` works. Because you're working with observables inside this map we can use something like `mergeMap()` which will handle the subscription and piping through of values automatically.

```js
setRenewalInterval() {
  // ...
  return this.timerSub = interval(CUSTOM_INTERVAL * 1000)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(() => {
        if (this.isLoggedIn && !tokenHelper.isTokenExpired()) {
          return this.getNewToken();
        } else {
          return this.setLogOut();
        }
      })   
    )
    .subscribe(x => {
      // x is the result of every call to getNewToken() or setLogOut()
    });
 }
```